# Не записывается в датафрейм значение после функции по категоризации данных

Tags: python, pandas

Есть таблица, в которой нужно категоризировать данные по 2 столбцам: пол и возраст, и добавить столбец в таблицу с этими категориями. После функции данные не записываются в столбец. Возникает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку?

Таблица вот: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C_EzH6ACY3M7c2W1gW_A5GDpwYAGPQFt/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106434889534507496883&rtpof=true&sd=true

код:

```
# категоризируем данные

def age_category(df):
  if (df['age_for_service_date'] <= 17) and (df['sex_id'] == 1):
    return '1.1'
  if (df['age_for_service_date'] <= 17) and (df['sex_id'] == 2):
    return '1.2'
  if (18 <= df['age_for_service_date'] <= 59) and (df['sex_id'] == 1):
        return '2.1'
  if (18 <= df['age_for_service_date'] <= 54) and (df['sex_id'] == 2):
    return '2.2'
  if (df['age_for_service_date'] >= 60) and (df['sex_id'] == 1):
    return '3.1'
  if (df['age_for_service_date'] >= 55) and (df['sex_id'] == 2):
    return '3.2'

df['age_category'] = df.apply(age_category, axis=1)

df.head()
```

Comment: Я тестировал ваш код (с `df = pd.read_excel("data_test_task_2022.xlsx"`), никаких проблем не было, на выводе я получил красивых 5 строк датафрейма и со столбцом `'age_category'`, в котором были все значения (правильно) `2.2`.

Comment: Тестировал на pandas 1.2.4.

Comment: Интеренсно... Я работаю в коллаб, у меня вот такая ошибка возникает. Неужели это от среды работы зависит. Попробую в юпитер онлайн сделать.

Answer (score 1):

я бы вообще предложил использовать родной инструментарий pandas, типа:

```
df["age_category"] = pd.NA
df.loc[df["sex_id"]==1, "age_category"] = pd.cut(df.loc[df["sex_id"]==1, "age_for_service_date"],
                            [0, 17, 59, 100], labels=["1.1", "2.1" ,"3.1"], include_lowest=True)
df.loc[df["sex_id"]==2, "age_category"] = pd.cut(df.loc[df["sex_id"]==2, "age_for_service_date"],
                            [0, 17, 54, 100], labels=["1.2", "2.2" ,"3.2"], include_lowest=True)
```

разумеется, результат нужно проверить.

Comment: Спасибо, Идея интересная. Код исполнен, но в результате появилось много Наннов.

Comment: ну вы же не прям скопировали мой код и запустили? ) он же перезапишет на нан неподходящие категории

Comment: я исправил ответ. единственное - проверьте диапазоны возрастов (граничные значения)

Comment: спасибо, попробовала. Диапазон возрастов верный, ну только не 100 а 83 поставила. но всё же 402 nan появилось...

Comment: Код Ваш скопировала и запустила.

Comment: Я снова обновил ответ - у вас нижние значения диапазона не учитывались - возраст 0, например, выпадал из диапазона. я включил нижние границы в бины. теперь у вас nan только там, где sex_id не определен.

Comment: Да, я отсортировала таблицу с нан, и уидела, что там только 0 - возраст! Сейчас ещё раз проверю!

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!))) Всё получилось! Никаких пропусков. Всё записалось красиво и правильно!)

Comment: на здоровье! на будущее помните, что почти все, что вы раньше делали с помощью циклов и иных итераций в обычном питоне  -  в пандас имеет векторизованные высокоэффективные и изящные аналоги.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)